# Problems with mockito. Unit test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm unit testing with mockito and I get nulls in the repository, after doing a .save().

My test:

```
....
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // USUARIO
        user = new User();
        user.setUserName("Username A");
        user.setPassword("Pass A");
        user.setConfirmPassword("Pass A");
    }


    @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
    @Test
    void createUserNoExistValidConfirmation() throws Exception {
        User userToPassParam = new User();
        userToPassParam.setUserName("Username_Aa");
        userToPassParam.setPassword("Pass A");
        userToPassParam.setConfirmPassword("Pass A");
        // checkUserNameAvailable
        Mockito.when(userDaoRepository.findByUserName(userToPassParam.getUserName())).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(user));
        // -- checkPasswordValid
        Mockito.when(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userToPassParam.getPassword())).thenReturn(user.getPassword());
        // -- save
        Mockito.when(userDaoRepository.save(userToPassParam)).thenReturn(user);

        User userToCallServiceImpl = new User();
        userToCallServiceImpl.setUserName("Username A");
        userToCallServiceImpl.setPassword("Pass A");
        userToCallServiceImpl.setConfirmPassword("Pass A");
        User user = userServiceImpl.createUser(userToCallServiceImpl); // HERE GET NULLS

        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("this.user: " + this.user);
        Assertions.assertEquals(user.getUserName(), this.user.getUserName());
    }
.....
```

value of userToPassParam passed parameter:  [image]
the expected object
[image]

I only treat 3 values of the object, "userName, password, confirmPassword" the other values do not matter to me.

When I try to pass the test:  userServiceImpl

```
@Override
public User createUser(User user) throws Exception {
    if (checkUserNameAvailable(user) && checkPasswordValid(user)) {
        // cogemos el estado de la DB para más adelante: user = save()
        String encodePassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodePassword);
        user = userDaoRepository.save(user);
    }
    return user;
}
```

[image]

The user has a "before save" value. Right when it saves I get a null.
[image]

After repository.save(object) the object returned by the .save "mock object" is null.

I don't understand very well why the .save returns null, when in the "when" I specify what to return.
It's as if mockito didn't intercept the .save() to return the object.

Note: I use Junit 5, Mockito 4.6.1

I am expecting the .save() to return the "user" as I specified in my @BeforeEach void setUp() {...}.
Mockito.when(userDaoRepository.save(userToPassParam)).thenReturn(user);
That is, the intercept of the .save() so that it returns the object.

Comment: Yes, it implements them.

Comment: Can you show us what the `User` class looks like and what `checkUserNameAvailable()` and `checkPasswordValid()` does?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the existing object (`userToPassParam`) instead of instantiating a new one with the same parameters (`userToCallServiceImpl`)? It would work in this case: `User user = userServiceImpl.createUser(userToPassParam);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have fixed this with an ArgumentMatchers. For some unknown reason, Mockito needs it.

> import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
>
> Mockito.when(userDaoRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);

Information source: [here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-mockito-unable-to-mock-save-method/)

*Note: I have also implemented equals and hashCode overrides, but it doesn't detect them.*

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really fix your test though, because now your test allows any user to be passed to `userDaoRepository.save()`. What happens if you put `verify(userDaoRepository).save(user)` below your assertions? The benefit of using `verify()` is that it gives a detailed failure message.

Comment: I have replied with an image.

Comment: @NasloFlaquez FWIW, deleting your own post makes all the downvote points go back to the original people, so no points lost bud. Do you equally blame and yell at your doctor whenever you accidentally stub your toe?...that's what you're currently doing with your MongoDB rant.